# Laravel: How to show a list of available time slots

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

Making a Laravel project where people can reserve some products for **1.5 hours**.

In my controller, I am querying a variable of time slots that have already been reserved.

Next I want to withdraw those time slots out of the available time slots.

```
$filteredTimeSlots = DB::table('timeslots')
        ->join('reservations', 'timeslots.id', '=', 'reservations.timeslot_id')
        ->where('product_id', $product->id)
        ->get();

    $timeslots = Timeslot::all();
```

Right now `$timeslots` holds all the time slots. But in here are also those slots that have been specified in `$filteredTimeSlots`.

In total I have **6 products**. Each can have reservations at the same time slots. So that's why I added the 'where' statement.

It's probably an easy fix but could not seem to find a clear solution on the Laravel documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you searched "MySQL available time slots" on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+available+time+slots you didn't find a MySQL query which you could transform into laravel code?.. Besides it's hard to help you when you not include example data and expected output  "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Out of what I found online I though I had to somehow transform a NOT IN query. Tried transforming that but it appears that did not resolve the challenge :)

Answer (score 2):

To find the remaining slots you want to make use of a left join where a slot hasnt been filled:

```
$timeslotsRemaining = DB::table('timeslots')
    ->leftJoin('reservations', 'timeslots.id', '=', 'reservations.timeslot_id')
    ->whereNull('reservations.timeslot_id')
    ->get();
```